# Javascript mouseover run function, then wait and run again

Tags: javascript, timer, mouseover

I am trying to get a function to fire on mouseover of an element. However, if the function is already running I want it to not fire.

I have this for the mouseover trigger

```
onmouseover="runFunc()">
```

and I have this for the js:

```
var timerStarted = false;

function waitToStart() {
  timerStarted = false;
}


function runFunc() {

  if (!timerStarted) {

     console.log('run function');
   } 

   timerStarted = true;
   setTimeout(waitToStart, 6000);
}
```

When I first hover over the element, I get

> run function

and nothing happens for 6 seconds which seemed like it was working. However after 6 seconds the console output counted fast up to the amount of times I hovered over the function:

> (24) run function

I'm struggling to understand why and how to make sure that the function only fires every 6 seconds after mouseover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're starting *many* timers. And eventually they all end and each set your boolean to false, even when in the half second before that you still started *yet another* timer.

What you really want is to either *cancel* any previously launched timer before issuing a new one, or to only launch a new one when you are sure the preceding one already timed out. The effect is a bit different: the first solution will reset the countdown with *every* mousemove (so must hold it still for at least 6 seconds), while the second will just make sure that there are at least 6 seconds between executions of the `if` block.

Here is how the second approach works:

```
var timerStarted = false;

function waitToStart() {
  timerStarted = false;
}

function runFunc() {
   if (!timerStarted) {
      console.log('run function');
      timerStarted = true;           // <--- moved inside the IF block
      setTimeout(waitToStart, 6000); //
   } 
}
```